# Error: API (SearchDisplay, save) does not exist

Tags: upgrade, extension, api

I upgraded CiviCRM (from 5.53 to 5.58) after disabling non native CiviCRM extensions and when I want to enable these extensions again, I get an error message I don't understand:

> Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the
> moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider
> with more details about what action you were performing when this
> occurred. API (SearchDisplay, save) does not exist (join the API team
> and implement it!)

These extensions are belgianpostcodes, moregreetings and formercommunicationsdata. For the moment, only belgianpostcodes is enabled.

Everything seems to work, but the error message keeps appearing each time I go to the CiviCRM Extensions page: `wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2Fextensions&reset=1`

I would like to get rid of the message, and obviously any error behind this message.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you have an extension(SearchKit) missing to be installed which is not required by CiviCRM

Can you visit Admin status page `/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fa%2F#/status` to check if there is any error message for require to install extension

Comment: The message disappeared without me understanding why...